# Calculate Max over time on sum function in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

I am running **prometheus** in my **kubernetes** cluster.
I have the following system in kubernetes:

I have 4 nodes. I want to calculate free memory. I want to have the summation of those four nodes. Then I want to find the maximum over 1 day. So, for example,

at time=t1
node1: 500 MB
node2: 600 MB
node3: 200 MB
node4: 300 MB
Total = 1700 MB

at time=t2
node1: 400 MB
node2: 700 MB
node3: 100 MB
node4: 200 MB
Total = 1300 MB

at time=t3
node1: 600 MB
node2: 800 MB
node3: 1200 MB
node4: 1300 MB
Total = 3900 MB

at time=t4
node1: 100 MB
node2: 200 MB
node3: 300 MB
node4: 400 MB
Total = 1000 MB

So, The answer to my query should be 3900 MB. I am not able to do max_over_time for the sum.

I have done like this(which is not working at all):

```
max_over_time(sum(node_memory_MemFree)[2m])
```

Answer (score 17):

[Since](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) version 2.7 (Jan 2019), Prometheus supports sub-queries:

```
max_over_time( sum(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance=~"foobar.*"})[1d:1h] )
```

(metric for the past 2 days, with a resolution of 1 hour.)

Read the documentation for more informations on using recording rules:  https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#subquery

However, do note the blog recommendation:

> **Epilogue**
>
> Though subqueries are very convenient to use in place of recording rules, using them unnecessarily has performance implications. Heavy subqueries should eventually be converted to recording rules for efficiency.
>
> It is also not recommended to have subqueries inside a recording rule. Rather create more recording rules if you do need to use subqueries in a recording rule.

The use of recording rules is explained in brian brazil article:
 https://www.robustperception.io/composing-range-vector-functions-in-promql/

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in one expression, you need to use a recording rule for the intermediate expression. See 
https://www.robustperception.io/composing-range-vector-functions-in-promql/

Comment: It's possible [since](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) Prometheus 2.7, using sub-queries.